# error using SQLite to save and return data

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to collect data from 3 edit texts and save it for use in another activity.
the code is as follows (i've edited the code to show only one edittext for convinence)

```
            EditText holdersala = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rawsalary);

            String holdersalary = holdersala.getText().toString();
            final int salary = Integer.parseInt(holdersalary);

     SQLiteDatabase datab = openOrCreateDatabase("yourdata", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
      datab.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MainData (Salafig INT);");
      datab.execSQL("INSERT INTO MainData VALUES (@salary);");
          datab.close();
```

then i retrive this information in another activity and save it into a textview

```
    TextView bn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.budget_need);


    SQLiteDatabase datab = openOrCreateDatabase("yourdata", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor c = datab.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MainData", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    bn.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Salafig")));
    datab.close();
```

for some reason when i run the app the textview is blank. please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code for your openOrCreateDatabase()?

Answer (score 0):

Got a few suggestions here. SQLite is a bit different from regular SQL =)

Your first `datab.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MainData (Salafig INT);");` should look like the following:

```
  datab.execSQL("CREATE TABLE MainData (Salafig INTEGER);");
```

SQLite won't overwrite your table if it already exists, and integer is used in place of int.

Your second query `datab.execSQL("INSERT INTO MainData VALUES (@salary);");` should be replaced with:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Salafig", salary);
    datab.insert("MainData", null, values);
```

Lastly your `bn.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Salafig")));` should be replaced with:

```
bn.setText(c.getInt("Salafig") + "");
```

Comment: thanks man! appreciate it! i get an error for the "getInt" in bn.setText(c.getInt("Salafig") + "");